# How to align dynamically generated span elements side by side using css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

Span elements are not static, they will be generated dynamically through java script code.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="chartsHolder" id="chartsPart">
<span class="charts" id="Chart"></span>
</div>
```

**less code Used:**

```
.chartsHolder {
    width:100%; 
}
.charts {
    display:inline-block;
    height:350px;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

I have attached the screen shot of graphs, please check it. [graphs are displaying one after the other, but I wanted them to display side by side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fhCT.jpg)

If this could be achieved through jquery means please suggest me.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I used your snippet, but it is not working. charts are displaying one after the other with 50% width. when I inspect the span element "chart", I could see two div elements are created inside span elements with (style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;) to display two charts.

Comment: i have used width 48% not 50%

Comment: okay, If I change that to 48% or 46% then also it is not displaying side by side. It is displaying one after the other.

Comment: you need to chow me a link so that i can check and let you know

Comment: how can I do that, I am new to this so can you please help me.

Comment: give me you website url where you used it? or create a fiddle example link

Comment: also you need to reduce width until they not come side-by-side (may be they need more decrements in width like 42%,41%..)